# How do I align the lines in the following multiple tables?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

There are some other questions related to this issue in the community, but I struggle to adapt this to my particular case. I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}[hbtp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Relevant indicators (Cluster 1)}}                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{GDP growth (annual \%)}                 & Reserves and related items (\% GDP)             \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Claims on central government (\% GDP)}}  & Current account balance (\% GDP)                \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Commercial service exports (\% GDP)}}    & \textbf{Gross capital formation (\% GDP)}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Commercial service imports (\% GDP)}}    & \textbf{Gross domestic savings (\% GDP)}                 \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Consumer price index (\% change)}       & Total reserves (includes gold, \% GDP)          \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Imports of goods and services (\% GDP)} & \textbf{FDI, net inflows (\% GDP)}
\end{tabular}
\label{tableCL1}

\bigskip

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Relevant indicators (Cluster 2)}}                                        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{GDP growth (annual \%)}}                & Current account balance (\% GDP)       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Claims on central government (\% GDP)} & Gross capital formation (\% GDP)       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Consumer price index (\% change)}      & \textbf{Total reserves (includes gold, \% GDP)} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Reserves and related items (\% GDP)}   & \textbf{Exports of goods and services (\% GDP)}
\end{tabular}
\label{tableCL2}

\bigskip

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Relevant indicators (Cluster 3)}}                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{GDP growth (annual \%)}                 & Current account balance (\% GDP)       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Claims on central government (\% GDP)}}  & Gross capital formation (\% GDP)       \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Commercial service exports (\% GDP)}    & Gross domestic savings (\% GDP)        \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Consumer price index (\% change)}}       & Exports of goods and services (\% GDP) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Reserves and related items (\% GDP)}    & Total reserves (includes gold, \% GDP) \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Imports of goods and services (\% GDP)} &                                       
\end{tabular}
\caption{The macroeconomic indicators recovered by the panel analogue of the elastic net. The indicators in bold are significant at the 5\% level.}
\label{tableCL3}
\end{table}
```

the outcome of which is as follows:

[image]

However, as you can see the centre lines (marked with red) are not aligned. How can this be accomplished? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That can be a pdf viewer issue. Have you tried printing or zooming in?

Comment: Do you mean vertical or horizontal alignment?  I think you mean horizontal, that is, the result should appear as if there is only one discontinuous vertical line.  If so, please fix the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to focus on making sure that the tables don't exceed the width of the text block. At present, nothing in your code assures this typographical criterion. I would like to suggest that you load the `tabularx` package and employ its eponymous environment to achieve your typesetting objective. This approach will also let you get ready of a lot of visual formatting code clutter. I addition, I'd like to suggest that you encase all three tabular-like structures in `subtable` environments and give each `subtable` a `\caption` directive of its own. That way, you can tell LaTeX to create cross-references to individual subtables and not just the table as a whole.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subtable]{font=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}


\begin{table}[hbtp!]
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}

\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{Relevant indicators, Cluster 1}
\label{tableCL1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L|L @{}}
\hline
GDP growth (\% p.a.)
  & Reserves and related items  \\
\textbf{Claims on central government }
  & Current account balance  \\
\textbf{Commercial service exports }
  & \textbf{Gross capital formation } \\
\textbf{Commercial service imports }
  & \textbf{Gross domestic savings } \\
Cons.\ price index growth (\% p.a.)
  & Total reserves (incl.\ gold) \\
Imports of goods and services 
  & \textbf{FDI, net inflows }
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\bigskip
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{Relevant indicators, Cluster 2}
\label{tableCL2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L|L @{}}
\hline
\textbf{GDP growth} (\% p.a.)
  & Current account balance        \\
Claims on central government  
  & Gross capital formation        \\
Cons.\ price index growth (\% p.a.)   
  & \textbf{Total reserves (incl.\ gold)} \\
Reserves and related items  
  & \textbf{Exports of goods and services }
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\bigskip
\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}
\caption{Relevant indicators, Cluster 3}
\label{tableCL3}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L|L @{}}
\hline
GDP growth (\% p.a.)
  & Current account balance        \\
\textbf{Claims on central government }
  & Gross capital formation        \\
Commercial service exports 
  & Gross domestic savings         \\
\textbf{Cons.\ price index growth} (\% p.a.)
  & Exports of goods and services  \\
Reserves and related items 
  & Total reserves (incl.\ gold) \\
Imports of goods and services  &                                       
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\caption{The macroeconomic indicators recovered by the panel analogue of the elastic net. The indicators in bold are statistically significant at the 5\% level. All indicators are measured in \% of GDP unless indicated otherwise.}
\label{tableCL}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! If I exclude the subtables it works like a charm. However, the issue is that I have a massive document where the subfigure package has also been used and these two packages (i.e., subcaption and subfigure) seem to clash. I do not wish to change every single figure because of this table. Is there a way to implement this without the use of the subcaption package? Thanks

Comment: @Carl - The `subfigure` has been deprecated for roughly 20 years or so. Don't believe me? Then please check out the header line at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure. It starts with "subfigure – Deprecated". The package's description on that webpage ends with "The package is now considered obsolete: it was superseded by `subfig`, but users may find the more recent `subcaption` package more satisfactory." In short, do yourself a favor and wean yourself off of the `subfigure` package.